# What would be the best way to make an app out of a website - the one that saves data locally?

Tags: android, ios, mobile

I have an online travel guide and I want to make an iphone/android app out of it.

It should be pretty simple: I just want exactly the same pages as the website, looking exactly the same (it's mobile-friendly) but all saved inside the app, so my readers can access it without the internet connection.

Do you know if there's any easy way of doing that? And what technical problems I might encounter?

Thank you!

PS sorry if it seems like a general question, but that's why I'm asking: to know more specifically what the possible problems might be.

Comment: I think this image from the website of [**phonegap**](http://phonegap.com/) says it all: http://phonegap.com/css/images/devapp_hero.svg

Comment: But there are many other frameworks that allow you to package a website into a native application just like phonegap does.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an HTML5 app with all the pages of your website that runs locally on your phone.

Check out **Phonegap**. It's mobile app framework thats uses **HTML, CSS,** and **Javascript**. The great thing about it is you can make publish phonegap apps to multiple devices - iOS, Android, Windows and more. http://www.phonegap.com/

There is a slight learning curve but once you learn it you will come to find that it is very easy.

Here is an example of apps built with Phonegap. http://phonegap.com/app/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! And do you know if my website is based on Drupal / would I be able to quickly convert it into static pages or there's another better solution for that?